# One word translation for spiraling or ballooning

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

I'm struggling to find a proper translation for "ballooning/spiraling" as in "ballooning public debt". Basically, it's about something growing very fast. Ideally, I want one word, an adjective, nor a verb. *Creciente* doesn't quite capture the speed of it. *Explosivo* might get closer but I am not convinced, as the key is not about violence but increasing speed. *Desbordado* doesn't sound appropriate either. A two word solution might be *crecimiento acelerado*. Do you have a suggestion for one word?

Comment: Qué te parece ‘exponential’?

Comment: @Traveller: It would be "exponencial" in Spanish. But it would be "crecimiento exponencial", that is, two words.

Comment: I would discourage the informal use of 'exponential' to mean 'very fast' when one talks about a variable that can be measured, since it has a specific mathematical meaning (growing as fast as fixed quantity exponentiated to a value that is proportional to time) which becomes shadowed by its imprecise counterpart. This is true both in Spanish and in English.

Comment: I totally agree with you, @GuillermoBCN. In the same way, "crecimiento muy rápido" and "crecimiento acelerado" don't have the same meaning.

Comment: @Charo, sure, that is another good example.

Answer (score 12):

¿Qué te parece el verbo **disparar**? En el propio DRAE aparece un ejemplo parecido al tuyo

**[disparar](https://dle.rae.es/?w=disparar)**

> 5. tr. Dicho de una cosa: Incrementar o hacer crecer sin moderación algo.
>      *La demanda disparó los precios*

growing very fast = crecer sin moderación algo

ballooning public debt = **disparando**(se) la deuda pública

Comment: Would it not be deuda disparandose since ballooning is intended as an adjective?

Comment: @mdewey I was not sure about the exact use intended by the OP. But in that case it should be "disparada" (participio), instead of "disparando" (gerundio).

Comment: I am fairly sure an adjective is meant here. The sentence might have been The country experienced a ballooning public debt. To be fair I would not have used spiralling in the same way, things are usually described as spiraling out of control.

Comment: @mdewey Yes, an adjective is meant.

Comment: @luchonacho You have just edited your question to include that information. Ballooning and spiraling are gerunds, in Spanish we don't use gerunds as adjectives. You should include a complete sentence to get better answers. Context is very important.

Comment: @luchonacho When you let loose a balloon we say that the balloon, el globo, goes "disparado", sale disparado. And the definition provided by the DRAE match almost perfectly your requirement "growing very fast"

Comment: @luchonacho A perfectly fine example in Spanish: "El cierre de empresas ha provocado una gran demanda de ayudas de desempleo, disparando la deuda pública" I'm not fluent enough in English but the last part can be translated as "ballooning the public debt", your requirement.

Comment: Exorbitante es un adjetivo y podria aplicar en esta situacion.

Comment: También funcionaría: "Con la deuda pública disparándose,..."

Comment: @DarkCygnus Para mí, exorbitante en este contexto denotaría que la deuda es muy grande, pero no transmite la idea de que está creciendo a gran velocidad.

Answer (score 6):

Could it be "deuda pública **astronómica**" or "deuda pública **asfixiante**" as it's choking the economy or society.

Also, "deuda pública galopante" implies that the debt is increasing fast

Comment: Galopante is a great word!

Comment: @luchonacho 

Answer (score 6):

While it may not carry some of the connotations that "ballooning" (growing rapidly as if you were inflating a balloon) or "spiraling" (show a continuous and dramatic increase) have, the DRAE includes "sobrecrecer"

> [Sobrecrecer](https://dle.rae.es/sobrecrecer?m=30_2)
>
> Exceder en crecimiento o crecer excesivamente.

As an advantage, it is one word.

> [...] la sobrecrecida deuda pública
>
> [...] la **sobrecreciente** deuda pública

Comment: Una respuesta sobre...saliente! No la conocía

Answer (score 2):

How about "aumento fulminante"?  This might be a little closer to ballooning than aumento explosivo.  It's still a little more violent than a balloon, but a little less so than explosivo.

Comment: Thanks but this is two words. Also, the word is not to be used as a verb.

Comment: @luchonacho Fulminante is an adjective.

Comment: @RubioRic Yes but the frase would be "aumento fulminante de la deuda publica", instead of e.g. "deuda publica explosiva".